# Calling a Servlet from a Java application

Tags: java, servlets, urlconnection

I want to call a Servlet from a Java application. The problem is, that the call seems not to reach the Servlet. I do not get any error, but do not reach the first output "doPost" in the Servlet. If I open the URL in a web browser, I got - of course - the error that GET is not supported etc., but at least I see, that something happens.

I use the following code (the ActionPackage class only holds a Vector of parameters and is Serializable):

Java application:

```
    ActionPackage p = new ActionPackage();
    p.addParameter("TEST", "VALUE");

    System.out.println(p);

    URL gwtServlet = null;
    try {
        gwtServlet = new URL("http://localhost:8888/app/PushServlet");
        HttpURLConnection servletConnection = (HttpURLConnection) gwtServlet.openConnection();
        servletConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(servletConnection.getOutputStream());
        objOut.writeObject(p);
        objOut.flush();
        objOut.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
public class PushServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("doPost");
    ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());

    ActionPackage p = null;
    try {
        p = (ActionPackage) objIn.readObject();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Servlet received p: "+p);       
}
```

}

Any ideas what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Dummy up a form page that submits to the PushServlet using `<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://localhost:8888/app/PushServlet">`.  I believe even a local HTML file would work as long as it submits to the servlet at the correct URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`URLConnection` is only lazily executed whenever you call any of the `get` methods.

Add the following to your code to *actually* execute the HTTP request and obtain the servlet response body.

```
InputStream response = servletConnection.getInputStream();
```

#### See also:

- [How to use `java.net.URLConnection` to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: Oh, right!  I forgot about that.  Also note that it's generally considered a good idea to read all the data out of the response InputStream, even if you don't care about its content.  This allows the JVM a better chance at being able to keep the connection alive for possible reuse later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After adding it, the call runs without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire body of the doPost in a try/catch block:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        System.out.println("doPost");
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        ActionPackage p = null;
        p = (ActionPackage) objIn.readObject();
        System.out.println("Servlet received p: "+p);       
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Then look again at your Servlet output log file or window for a new Exception which may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        System.out.println("doPost");
        ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        ActionPackage p = null;
        p = (ActionPackage) objIn.readObject();
        System.out.println("Servlet rece p: "+p);       
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```