# How to call a servlet from Java code

Tags: java, servlets

I want to call servlet with some parameters and receive a response. The code is written in Java.
What is the best (cleanest) way to do that?

Also, can i call a servlet and continue with the code withoud waiting the servlet to finish (close the connection and "forget about it")?

Comment: You can spin off your request into a separate `Thread` if you want to continue with other parts of your application.

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349854/calling-a-servlet-from-a-java-application

Comment: "What is the best (cleanest) way to do that" what does *best* or *cleanest* mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use Apache HttpClient API for handling and communication with servlet

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Features:

1. Param are easy to pass and parse response.
2. It allows even communicating thru Proxy
3. Open source
4. It also support Asyncronous
   and many more 
   Please refer the above url.

Answer (score 4):

Example from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

From your perspective, servlet is just an URL on some server. As for not waiting for a response - read about Java threads. But you cannot close the HTTP connection without waiting for a servlet to finish as this might cause a servlet to fail. Simply wait for the response in a separate thread and discard it if it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do i have to wait for a response (if the solution if to use a thread, than the answer is still yes - i have to wait for an answer). What about passing parameters to the servlet? do i have to bild the url by myself (using '?' and '&') or there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache HttpClient [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e37)

This also has Non-blocking I/O functionality available [NIO extensions](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/nio.html)

Here's a [Tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/non_blocking_http_client_with_apache_httpcomponen.html) for the Apache HttpComponents.

You could also try [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/HttpClient#Asynchronous_Exchanges) or [Async Http Client](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client)

Comment: i really dislike people who downvote with no comment. Here's an upvote to balance the force.

Answer (score 0):

For me [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/) was the shortest and most useful tutorial about [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/index.html).