# How to design a web parser to interact with an Applet?

Tags: java, applet, web-scraping

sorry if my question in trivial but I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically interact with an applet, reading the output it provides (a sort of web-scraping).

Assuming a certain website expose an applet, would it be possible to extract content from it through POST/GET requests (or other similar means) in a programming language like Java. My interaction is "black box like" as I have no access to the server environment.

Comment: One option is to behave like an applet, but I assume that requires that you know how the servlet/applet work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349854/calling-a-servlet-from-a-java-application

Comment: *"a certain website"*  Care to share an URL?

Comment: no, it's an italian website. No commercial value involved...just trying to make some money on our overcomplicated government rules providing accessible content to mobile users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. An applet is a `Swing` application running in the context of a browser and when you "hit" a URL for an applet the browser actually downloads the corresponding jar.
But there are ways to "manipulate" the applet and e.g. press a button or get a value programmatically and that is what automated UI suites do. I don't know how they do it though to be honest.Seems like a decompile and analysis on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if communication through JavaScript works for you, but you can call any public method in an applet from JavaScript like this:

<applet name=myapplet ...> </applet>

Your applet may have a method like this:

public String returnAString() {
 return "this is a string";

}

So to get a value back from that method, you would call it like this:

var stringFromApplet = document.myapplet.returnAString();

You can also make calls from an applet back to your JavaScript like this:

getAppletContext().showDocument("javascript:myJavaScriptMethod()");

Comment: I ended downloading the jar and decompiling it via JAD before reverse engineering all the Applet. It was really funny, and I learnt a lot in the process (a lot of black magick since the content was heavily obfuscated). Thank you for your time, I appreciated your effort..