# How to call /bin/wcmcommand servlet class from Java Class in CQ5

Tags: java, servlets, httpclient, aem, wcm

How to call "/bin/wcmcommand" servlet that has been inside Out of box CQ5 Jar from Java Class. HTTPClient and URL Connection both the way i am not able to make a POST call to this servlet. i am getting ERROR CODE:500.

Comment: What, have you taken the source for the servlet and copied it into another project or is the servlet running in situ within CQ's OSGi runtime?

Comment: Servlet is running in inside CQ bundle. OOTB features is servlet called from   JSP. But i want to call that servlet from My java class.

Comment: Not what a servlet is designed for really. Arguably better to copy the source of whatever behaviour you wish to consume and package inside your own class.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you meant by "servlet that has been inside Out of box CQ5 Jar" .
What I understood from your question is , you want to call (`HTTP GET/POST`) a servlet from a Java class (and not from JSP !).

I assume its a Sling Servlet and has been registered with a path/resource type or any other [valid way of registering a servlet.](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html)

If its registered with a "`path`" , you can trigger a HTTP request in many ways .

- [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)
- [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

**References:**

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

[calling a servlet from a java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368375/calling-a-servlet-from-a-java-class?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This OOTB Sling servlet only accepts sling request object. so can't call directly using  HTTPClient in java class like normal servlet.
But my problem got resolved using servlet communication. I have changed calling class from java class to Sling servlet class then i communicated using servlet communication like this.

```
RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("/bin/wcmcommand");
req.include(request,response);
```

I want to call this servlet using multiple times with different value.
So i have used `SlingServletRequestWrapper` class for modifying the `request.getParameter()` value each and every call.